# What commands are deprecated by systemd

Tags: systemd, sysvinit

I recently came across [this awesome list](https://dougvitale.wordpress.com/2011/12/21/deprecated-linux-networking-commands-and-their-replacements/), which lists all the command line tools, that are *deprecated* (or let's say *whose functionality can be replicated*) by the new `ip` tool.

Recently trying to get accustomed to `systemd`, I learned that almost all functionality of `cron` can be replicated by `systemd`. What are other tools whose functionality can be replicated by `systemd`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The obvious ones - these are what `systemctl` replaces:

- `service`
- `chkconfig` on redhat and `update-rc.d` on debian, *if* a systemd unit has been written for the service.
- `reboot`, `poweroff`, `halt`, `telinit`.
- `pm-suspend` and friends have apparently gone away.  As a cross-distro effort it's the sort of thing that `systemd` aims to accomplish; it's just interesting given the hooks and quirks that `pm-utils` supported, and I'm not aware of any fallout from systemd replacing it.

Also `systemd-analyze` provides a similar function to bootchart.

As pointed out by others, it probably makes more sense to enumerate the files provided by systemd, or the documentation.  By doing so, I noticed one more obscure command, `runlevel`.

systemd only emulates runlevels, so `runlevel` is another of the legacy commands.  Searching for an equivalent command turned up `systemctl list-units --type target` (note `list-units` only shows active units unless directed otherwise).  The output is not as obvious, because targets tend to depend on other targets, and you can have multiple targets active at once, independent or overlapping.

However for now I can't think exactly when you would use the `runlevel` command.  I have an impression it would be used interactively as a summary of the state of the init system.  In which case, the better alternative would be `systemctl status`.

Comment: Debian and co's `service` command stops associated sockets when stopping services, so I still stick to it instead of `systemctl`.

Answer (score 2):

You could browse the man pages that systemd comes with. On my fedora 22 I see

```
$ rpm -ql systemd | grep -c man1
  32
$ rpm -ql systemd | grep -c man8
  111
```

32 man pages for commands like `localectl`, and 111 pages on features like `systemd-timedated`. Alternatively, look through `apropos systemd`.

Comment: Nice. I note this also shows e.g. the manpage for `reboot`, a command which systemd provides for compatibility but which it describes as "legacy only".